# Creating a NuGet package. Need clarification about included dependencies

Tags: xml, nuget, nuget-package

This is the first time I'm experimenting creating a NuGet package, and I'm a little confused about one thing:

**If I reference other external NuGet packages (e.g., Ninject, Automapper, etc.) inside the project that I'm using to build my own custom NuGet package, how should I handle those dependencies when my package gets eventually consumed/installed in an actual project?**

From my initial experimentation so far, the generated NuGet package detects those other dependencies (Ninject, Automapper, etc.), and displays them under the ***Dependencies*** section in NuGet UI.  Then, when I click Install, it actually pulls down and installs Ninject/Automapper from Nuget.org.

This is where I'm confused.  Aren't Ninject/Automapper assemblies part of my created nuget package assembly by then?  Shouldn't the consumer of my custom NuGet package not care/see that they depend on Ninject/Automapper?

### Additional Background Info

These are the steps I took so far to create my custom NuGet package:

1. Created the **.nuspec** file by executing the following (inside the same folder where the **MyProject.csproj** file is located):

   ```
   nuget.exe spec
   ```
2. Created the actual package file (**.nupkg**) by executing:

   ```
   nuget.exe pack MyProject.csproj
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You followed correct set of steps to create the package. Your package has the dependencies which are listed in the nuspec file once you generate the package.
It is in the interest of the consumer of your package to understand what the dependencies are. Furthermore, you can also specify which range of versions are valid dependencies. This i useful if the consumer of your package already has installed required dependency that may be higher than the minimal necessary by your package.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've come to realize this myself as well.  I was getting hung up on basics of assembly dependencies.